# PHP & mongodb query like sql

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

This is the sql query.

```
$str = "SELECT DATE(sold_dt) AS dt, COUNT(*) AS count FROM temp GROUP BY DATE(sold_dt) ORDER BY dt desc limit 50";
$query = $this->db->query($str);
$data = $query->result_array();
```

I'd like to use mongodb instead of mysql in my php projects.

```
$filter = ['sold_dt']; 
$options = [ 'projection' => ['_id' => 0], 
              'sort' => ['sold_dt' => -1], 
              'group' => ['_id' => 'Date(sold_dt)'], 
              'limit' => 20 ]; 
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options); 
$cursor = $db->executeQuery($db.".". $tempTable, $query); 
$data= $cursor->toArray();
```

I am not sure it is correct and as you can see aggregate is missed.
I am going to complete this query.
How can I do this using executeQuery() or executeCommand()?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "How do I convert the database in my application from SQL to something completely different?" is not a question we can answer without it taking a lot of time to understand your problem, and where you might have issues. **Try something** and if you have problems let us know.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would like to know how to convert that sql query to mongo query. Only this.

Comment: Your question is equivalent to "I would like to learn how to fly a plane. Only this." Do you have a MongoDB schema? Do you have anything Mongo yet? If the answer is "no" then do that first.

Comment: As you can see my SQL query, it returns array of dt and counts.
What I want to know is how can I get the same result using mongo query in php.

Comment: There is no way to simply "translate" this. It depends *entirely* on your MongoDB schema. If you don't have one the answer is to **make one first**.

Comment: I migrated sql to mongo using studio 3T. And I don't need any code to convert that sql query to mongo query. what I want is to know how can I get the same result using mongo query.

Comment: $filter = ['sold_dt'];
$options = [
    'projection' => ['_id' => 0],
    'sort' => ['sold_dt' => -1],
    'group' => ['_id' => 'Date(sold_dt)'],
    'limit' => 20
];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$cursor = $db->executeQuery($db.".". $tempTable, $query);
$data= $cursor->toArray();

I'd like to complete this query.

Comment: That's better, but unreadable as a comment. Edit your question and include those useful details.

Comment: sorry, I will do that.

Comment: I modified my questions. So could you give me a favor?